# jQuery / Javascript > onClick place text at last known cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form I'm working with that allows the user to continually add new rows as needed (used for making an article with multiple "howto" steps, they can click over and over again to add a new step).  What I would like to be able to do is have the user be able to click in any of those rows at any time and then click on a word or button that is off to the side that will then insert the value of that button into the last known cursor position.

So for example I may have one form that currently has 3 rows.  If the user goes back and wants to insert some data they could click back in the box and hit the button corresponding to the data they want to insert.

Example input 1: "Remove the customers current IP address and replace with their static IP, [USER COULD CLICK HERE AND THEN CLICK THE STATIC IP BUTTON AND %STATIC_IP% WOULD BE INSERTED AT THE LAST KNOWN CURSOR POSITION (AKA HERE)]

Example input 2: "Enter in the customers [Click to insert %WIFI_SSID%] into the router settings"

I have found several other stackoverflow articles that are able to all insert text but they all expect it to be into a defined textarea or input.  In this case I'm needing it to insert into the last known cursor position.  I hope this is all clear.  I look forward to any assistance or questions.

Starter code: http://jsfiddle.net/4mJwU/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know how to insert some arbitrary content at the last known caret position, your only problem is to know which field was focues last time before button was clicked.

That can be done in numerous number of ways, one of those would be utilize focus and blur events (attached to fields - rows in your case) to track (in some variable for example) reference to the field last focused. It should be a piece of cake from there.

Quick and simple script that can get you started http://jsfiddle.net/sjqWu/1/

Combine what you've learned from other stackoverflow anwsers with example above and you should be ok. Happy learning!

Comment: I do not know how to do any of it.  That's my whole question ;)  The only thing I know how to do would be to append to a certain textarea/input.  But here I need to add wherever the cursor was just at, regardless of which textbox/textarea it was.

Comment: I've added some basic example (without the insert at caret code, but that you can find all over the internet).

Comment: It seems like I'm pretty close with this: http://jsfiddle.net/RbZcC/.  it only works though if I replace lastFocused with 'test1' to specify the exact input.  Do I have incorrect syntax to reference the variable you created?

Answer (score 0):

I'd question your design. To make the user have to click a field then click some text to insert into that field seems like too many steps. You could possibly utilize some sort of drag and drop routine. Or instead of the first click being a text box, maybe make it a drop down list?

I agree with WTK. You can store the record id or text box id using some sort of event, then proceed from there.

Comment: Drag and drop instead of a click would be fine but the point of the insert is to allow for typing any type of task and have it reference something in the database upon printout.  So if I make a task and have inside it a reference to %STATIC_IP% php will replace that with the customers actual static IP when it actually displays the howto article.